# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'className.freezed.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

I am new to flutter and after searching everywhere I couldn't find the reason behind this error

Below is my code

```
// ignore: file_names
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'NetworkResponse.freezed.dart';
@freezed
  class NetworkResponse with _$NetworkResponse {
    const factory NetworkResponse.success(Map<String, dynamic> data) = OK;
    const factory NetworkResponse.error(String message) = ERROR;
    const factory NetworkResponse.loading(String message) = LOADING;
}
```

Error

[image]

```
1) Target of URI doesn't exist: 'NetworkResponse.freezed.dart'.
2) Classes can only mix in mixins and classes.dartmixin_of_non_class
3) The name 'OK' isn't a type and can't be used in a redirected constructor.
Try redirecting to a different constructor.
```

Code Source: https://betterprogramming.pub/building-generic-and-performant-networking-layer-in-flutter-b25c2b1b89a4

Comment: You must have the build_runner package installed in your project and then build it as described [here in the freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed) package readme. Ex `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Comment: Yes its already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for freezed generator to work, yours file names have to match.

I suspect that your file is not named `NetworkResponse.dart` since it is not a flutter convention. Flutter convention is to name files with snake case - `network_response.dart`. In this case, your freezed file would be `network_response.freezed.dart` and it should be the string following the `part` keyword.

With that implemented, you only have to run `flutter pub run build_runner build`. In case of any errors, `--delete-conflicting-outputs` flag should do the job. Also make sure to not only have `freezed_annotation` dependency in your pubspec.yaml but also `freezed` itself as a dev dependency.